# Trying to webscrape a page with beautifulsoup, getting a lot of element data (I assume) which I want to eliminate

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I have almost everything working but:

When getting a particular `div` with `class` I get a long response which is useless to me. On inspection I believe it is because the `div` doesn't end after the information I need.

I am trying to figure out the right way to only get the data I want. I know there is another way where I can exclude certain data?

Code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
contact_us = soup.find_all("div",{"class" : "contact_us"})
```

The output is a list which has just 1 item else I would use the loop method.

[LINK][1] - Link removed due to possible sensitive information.

Edit:

I want to get the:

Company Name
Contact Person 
Address:
Mobile:
Phone:

Comment: So what is the data you want?

Comment: @wpercy Ah..forgot to mention. I will just update it. Its the Company name, Address, Contact person, Phone numbers. 3AM brain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markup is not quite easy to work with, but we can use the `strong` elements as something we can rely on - locating `strong` elements one by one, use them as labels and something we can advance to [next siblings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings) until we meet an another `strong` element or reach the end:

```
from itertools import takewhile

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

url = "http://www.htavr.com/enquiry.html"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
contact_us = soup.select_one(".contact_us")

# remove all br elements to ease parsing
for br in contact_us.find_all("br"):
    br.unwrap()

labels = contact_us.find_all("strong")

# first strong element is a business name
business_name = labels[0].get_text()

not_tag = lambda elm: not isinstance(elm, Tag)

# going over all the strong "labels"
for label in labels[1:]:
    # extract all next text nodes before the next "strong" element or the end
    value = " ".join([text.strip() for text in takewhile(not_tag, label.next_siblings)])

    print(label.get_text(strip=True), value)
```

Prints:

```
Contact Person : <first_and_last_name> (Director)
Address : <address_here>
Mobile : <mobiles_here>
Phone : <telephones_here>
Call Us : <telephone_here>
```

(removed sensitive information from the answer)

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, Lots more reading ahead. :) Thanks for removing the personal info. Would the url in the answer be required for someone looking at the answer in the future? Also, now I must learn about how to use the data as a list. :)

Comment: getting an error on _Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 1, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, "html5lib")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'_

Comment: Looks like you probably just need to pass `source` to your soup constructor.

Comment: Oh...I just installed the `html5lib`. Seems to have caused some trouble with importing bs4. :(

Comment: Uninstalled `html5lib` and now bs4 works. Wondering how to install `html5lib` while keeping bs4 working.

Comment: @Sid ah, sorry for that, `html.parser` would also work perfectly in this case, no need for `html5lib`.